# How to report a bug where F11 does not exit full screen properly?

Tags: unity, google-chrome, compiz, bug-reporting

I've come a across a bug where F11 (the default shortcut to toggle full screen in two apps in question) sometimes does not exit full screen but instead shows the screen of an application running 'behind' it in full screen.  Mostly affects Atom and Chrome together.

How do I report this? More specifically who do I report it to, and what environment variables are relevant? Unity, Compiz, Google and Atom are all suspects.  You can view the behavior when I press F11 in this screen cast...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A95vDtOuaAo

I'm running 16.10, but I'm sure there are more variables to report.

Comment: I believe open source in general would benefit a great deal if there was more awareness/transparency around how to file a proper bug report.  It could even inspire more people to help fix them!

Answer (score 0):

[Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu) funnel is not as intimidating as I had imagined.

Comment: Realizing that it may not get addressed on LaunchPad  taking into account the scale of the project.  Welcoming any input...